# How to Allow Youtube Videos Using HTML Purifier

Tags: php, mysql, htmlpurifier

How do I allow youtube videos on my web page using HTML Purifier http://htmlpurifier.org/.

Can someone help me on this on their demo I have to check `Use experimental features`. How do I fix my code to allow youtube videos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[You could read their documentation...](http://htmlpurifier.org/docs/enduser-youtube.html)